# Adding file and fetching data from model to save in another model in django 3.0

Tags: python, django, web, django-views, django-forms

I'm trying to add a file in a form. In my views.py i am trying to fetch subject_id from subject model and session_year_id from SessionYearModel to save the data in my Notes model . But it is not processing.and gives a message of "Failed to add Notes". How to do that?
**Below is the code.**

> My views.py

```
def staff_add_notes_save(request):

if request.method != "POST":
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("staff_apply_leave"))
else:
    subject_id = request.POST.get("subject_id")
    session_year_id = request.POST.get("session_year_id")
    notesfile1 = request.FILES["notesfile"]

    subject_model = Subjects.objects.filter(id=subject_id)
    session_model = SessionYearModel.object.filter(id=session_year_id)

    try:
        notes = Notes.objects.create(subject_id=subject_model,session_year_id=session_model,notesfile=notesfile1)
        notes.save()
        messages.success(request, "Successfully added Notes")
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("staff_add_notes"))
    except:
        messages.error(request, "Failed to add Notes")
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("staff_add_notes"))
```

> staff_add_notes.html(TEMPLATE)

```
<form role="form" action="/staff_add_notes_save" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Subject </label>
                        <select class="form-control" name="subject" id="subject">
                            {% for subject in subjects %}
                            <option value="{{ subject.id }}">{{ subject.subject_name }}</option>
                            {% endfor %}
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Session Year</label>
                        <select class="form-control" name="session_year" id="session_year">
                            {% for session_year in session_years %}
                            <option value="{{ session_year.id }}">{{ session_year.session_start_year }} TO {{session_year.session_end_year }}</option>
                            {% endfor %}
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Add notes</label>
                        <input type="file"  name="notesfile" class="form-control"> 
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        {% if messages %}
                        {% for message in messages %}
                        {% if message.tags == 'error' %}
                        <div class="alert alert-danger" style="margin-top:10px">{{ message }}</div>
                        {% endif %}
                        {% if message.tags == 'success' %}
                        <div class="alert alert-success" style="margin-top:10px">{{ message }}</div>
                        {% endif %}
                        {% endfor %}
                        {% endif %}
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-footer">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Add Notes</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
```

***EDIT 1***
After removing try and except, below is code of views.py

```
def staff_add_notes_save(request):
if request.method != "POST":
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("staff_apply_leave"))
else:
    subject_id = request.POST.get("subject")
    session_year_id = request.POST.get("session_year")
    notesfile1 = request.FILES["notesfile"]

    subject_model = Subjects.objects.filter(id=subject_id)
    session_model = SessionYearModel.object.filter(id=session_year_id)
    notes_model = request.FILES["notesfile"]
    
    notes = Notes.objects.create(subject_id=subject_model,session_year_id=session_model, notesfile1=notes_model)
    notes.save()
    messages.success(request, "Successfully added Notes")
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("staff_add_notes"))
```

Error:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I assume `subject_model` contains one Subject and `session_model` contains one SessionYearModel.

Change your query for getting those to:

```
subject_model = Subjects.objects.get(id=subject_id)
session_model = SessionYearModel.objects.get(id=session_year_id)
```

Also, you don't want to try, except with specific exception. Any failure will be caught with this and thus does not give you any idea on what went wrong. Either catch a specific exception of remove the try, except.

The `create` method of the queryset api already saves the model. the save() method is therefore not necessary after calling create in your case.

**Edit 1**

The values in your post request dict are based on the name attributes of the field. Therefore, change subject_id and session_year_id to this:

```
subject_id = request.POST.get("subject")
session_year_id = request.POST.get("session_year")
```

***Edit 2***

```
class SessionYearModel(models.Model):
    id=models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    session_start_year=models.DateField()
    session_end_year=models.DateField()
    object=models.Manager()
```

Comment: Subjects matching query does not exist.   LINE which causing an errror is this.->
subject_model = Subjects.objects.get(id=subject_id)

Comment: @MIsmail that means there is no subject with the id = subject_id. Are you getting any value for `request.POST.get("subject_id")`?

Comment: yes, in my form, subjects and session year is showing.

Comment: I have also posted another question about profile pic if you can help in that one too. here is the link  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67709316/display-profile-image-of-a-customuser-in-django

Comment: @MIsmail the name attribute of the subject and session_year field in your form are not subject_id or session_year_id. See my edited answer.

Comment: I did as you told me, error popped up of failed to upload, then i removed try and except, then error was shown, plz see edit 1. THANKS

Comment: @MIsmail it looks like you still get the subject using `objects.filter()`. See my answer. Use `objects.get()`.

Comment: AttributeError.                                                                                                                   type object 'SessionYearModel' has no attribute 'objects'.                                                           Line :  session_model = SessionYearModel.objects.get(id=session_year_id)

Comment: @MIsmail is SessionYearModel a Model? Please add this model to your question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232952/discussion-between-m-ismail-and-vincent).