# Display profile image of a customuser in django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, web, view

I am trying to show the uploaded image of a student in student profile but its not working. ***Below is my code***

> Models.py

```
class Students(models.Model):
id=models.AutoField(primary_key=True) 
admin=models.OneToOneField(CustomUser,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
gender=models.CharField(max_length=255)
profile_pic = models.ImageField(null=True,blank=True)
address=models.TextField()
course_id=models.ForeignKey(Courses,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
session_year_id=models.ForeignKey(SessionYearModel,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
created_at=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
updated_at=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
fcm_token=models.TextField(default="")
objects = models.Manager()
```

> Views.py

```
def student_profile(request):
user=CustomUser.objects.get(id=request.user.id)
student=Students.objects.get(admin=user)
return render(request,"student_template/student_profile.html",{"user":user,"student":student})
```

> Template.

```
<img src="{{ request.admin.user.profile_pic.url  }}" class="img-circle elevation-2" alt="User Image">
```

***EDIT 1:***

[image]

[image]

Comment: plz check again

Answer (score 0):

You can get the profile picture of the user as follows:

```
<img src="{{ student.profile_pic.url }}" class="img-circle elevation-2" alt="User Image">
```

Comment: I did this but still ,pic is not available there.

Comment: Are you sure that student has a profile_pic? What is the value of `{{ student.profile_pic.url }}`? @MIsmail

Comment: Yes, plz check the edit 1, From admin section it image is uploaded and can be seen when admin is logged in, but when i sign in as student it can't be seen.